# Testing Google Maps API locally

Tags: testing, google-maps, local

I am trying to test Google Maps in development sites under IIS. My local testing URL is http://sitename/. As there is no “.com” in the name, I cannot obtain an API key. I can obtain a key for http://localhost/, but I am wondering if there is a way to use the testing URL http://sitename/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a fluke. For some reason, the key register page would not allow me to register the domain. After posting this question, I tried again and it gave me the key.

To use Google maps on a testing server, just register for the key with the testing name http://sitename/. This will also work for /localhost/.

Comment: Can you specify how did you set your referers on the API's Console? I've tried 'localhost' and Roger's solution with 'localtest.mysite' but I'm still not having luck

Answer (score 4):

While I don't know Google Maps' API details, you can locally alias a *.com domain to your own local server.  Add an entry to /etc/hosts (the equivalent on Windows is c:/windows/system32/etc/hosts, IIRC).

For example, you could add:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.yourotherdomain.com
# or
127.0.0.1   localtest.yourotherdomain.com
```

Comment: Great response. After posting, this dawned on me. Although I’ve not tried it, it should work. Thanks!

Comment: how do you do this on wamp?

Comment: Great idea Roger. The path is actually c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts.